# WEKA vs RDS (Rule Discovery System)

Tags: data-mining, software, weka

Between the two data mining software, which is easier to use: WEKA or RDS (Rule Discovery System)?

What are the pros and cons of both software?

Comment: Please be more specific: "easier to use" is vague and may cause unnecessary controversy or arguing.

Comment: easier to use means for absolute beginner in data mining, which one is more user friendly. I know that WEKA is more popular than RDS, but at first glance it doesnt look very simple to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know RDS but I looked briefly through the site and I have used Weka. Some advantages of Weka:

1. Developed by academia - I generally prefer this over private company software. One reason is that it is more transparent
2. As far as I remember Weka has hundreds of models/combinations. RDS looks much more limited. For example I couldn't find Support Vector Machines for RDS - that is a basic for a machine learning environment. It seems to me that RDS is more based on rule-mining, which is only a small part of what Weka can do.
3. Weka is written in Java and is easily extendible by your own models and such.

I personally found Weka very easy to use - but I haven't tried RDS so it might be easier. But I think Weka is definitely more powerful and flexible.

Comment: thank You @Bitwise.  I have tried a bit of RDS and it seemed easy to use so far but I will try to work with Weka.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for a alternative GUI for WEKA, you could try [KNIME](http://www.knime.org/) too. It is a bit more stable and offers some extra features. Personally I think KNIME is more intuitive to use than the standard WEKA GUI.

Comment: Thank you very much :D :D. I will take a look at the KNIME link that you sent.